# Determine whether a contour $f(x,y) = C$ is convex

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry

First of all, three dimension is more complex so let's restrict to two dimension here. Suppose a given contour $f(x,y) = C$ is closed--I don't know how to check the closeness mathematically, but let's just assume it is. I did some experiment, three typical examples are shown below. [image: contours]

By observation I have the following hypothesis about convexity if $f(x,y)$ is a polynomial:
all right hand side signs are positive, and all powers of $x$ and $y$ are even. This is supported by the counter examples in the middle and the right panel. But I am not sure if it is actually true.

A directly related question would be to generalize to arbitrary function $f(x,y)$.

Edit: I should add that what I mean is the **convexity of the region within the contour**. I guess the question is better changed to "determine whether the region inside a contour: $f(x,y)<=C$, is convex". I apologize for not expressing it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

> I have the following hypothesis about convexity if $f(x,y)$ is a polynomial: all right hand side signs are positive, and all powers of $x$ and $y$ are even

Your examples all have $f(x, y) = 1$ with the top-degree coefficients positive, so let's restrict to this special case.

Assuming the sign condition refers to the coefficients of $f$ (i.e., on the *left-hand* side), your hypothesis might mean: 1. the sign condition implies convexity of the (sub-)level sets of $f$, 2. convexity of the sub-level sets of $f$ implies the sign condition, 3. both, or 4. something else.

In any event, neither condition implies the other: If
$$
f(x, y) = x^{2} + y^{2}(1 + cy(1 + y)),
$$
the sub-level set $\{(x, y) : f(x, y) \leq 1\}$ is approximately circular, hence convex for $|c|$ sufficiently small. This proves that a polynomial containing an odd-degree term (with mixed-sign coefficients or not) can have a strictly convex sub-level set.

Conversely, if
$$
f(x, y) = x^{2} + y^{2} + cx^{2}y^{2},
$$
the sub-level set $\{(x, y) : f(x, y) \leq 1\}$ is not convex for $|c|$ sufficiently large, proving that a polynomial containing only even-degree terms with positive coefficients need not strictly convex sub-level sets.

Comment: `a polynomial containing an odd-degree term ... can have a strictly convex sub-level set` Right. Additionally, convexity is invariant to translations, while the presence of odd terms and the sign of the RHS depend on the chosen origin. For a simple example, translating the unit circle to $(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=1$ gives both odd terms and a negative RHS, though the circle is obviously a convex closed curve.

Answer (score 0):

Let suppose $f$ is enough nice function, such that  we can locally rewrite the curve $f(x,y)=C$ as graph of $y=g(x)$ for some $g$ around the point $(x_0, g(x_0))$ such that   $f(x_0, g(x_0))=C$. We can do this taking into account implicit function theorem! Then it is easy to check that the graph of $y=g(x)$ is convex subset of $R^2$ if and only if $g$ is linear function, i.e. $y=ax+b$  !

Comment: $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ is a an `enough nice` function, and $f(x,y)=1$ defines the unit circle, which is a convex closed curve.

Comment: It is clear as day that circle is not a convex set ! read definition of convex sets carefully !

Comment: The OP asks about the "contour", which I take to mean (also given the posted examples) the closed curve defined by the implicit equation. A circle is most definitely a [convex curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_curve): "*a convex curve is a curve in the Euclidean plane which lies completely on one side of each and every one of its tangent lines*".

Answer (score 0):

If the questioner by convexity of the level curves $f(x,y)=C$ He/She means the convexity of the sublevel set $f(x,y) \le C$, this is actually an equivalent definition of [Quasiconvex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function) functions. There are some characterization of this kind of functions in literatures, but not exactly what OP wants (a charterization in terms of sign of coefficients and exponents). Take look at my example below, it shows why thinking about this kind of characterization is not helpful.

For any  real numbers $\alpha,$ $\beta$, $\lambda$ and $n > 0$ the function $ f(x,y)=(\alpha x + \beta y + \lambda)^{n} $ has above property, but the parameters $\alpha,$ $\beta$, $\lambda$ and $n$ are free to choose  !

An another category of Quasiconvex functions is $ f(x,y)=(\alpha x  + \lambda)^{n} + (\beta y + t)^m.$

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see the direct relation to OP's question. Take $f(x,y)=(x+1)^2 + (y+2)^3$ for example, then the curve [$f(x,y)=5$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%2B1)%5E2+%2B+(y%2B2)%5E3%3D5) is neither closed nor convex.

Comment: Oh, you're right in later example $m,n$ have to be even natural numbers to guarantee each part $(...)^n$ and  $()^m$be convex function... still for different even $m$ and $n$ we can produce as many as odd powers as we want. 

Any way by direct relation you meant later example does not work for all $n$ and $m$? or whole answer is irreverent?

Comment: And in the first example $f(x,y)=C$ reduces to $\alpha x + \beta y + \lambda = \sqrt[n]{C}$ i.e. always a straight line. I don't see how this could be helping with OP's question.

Comment: That's only the matter of  misunderstanding of terminologies written in thisquestion, first it was about convexity of $f(x,y)=C$, (That's why I first wrote my first answer), second closeness of $f(x,y)=C$ (which I thought it is topological closeness which is automatic in continuous functions, so I wrote another example )

Comment: The curve being closed was part of the [original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2289818/1) (`given contour f(x,y)=C is closed`). Then, a closed curve being convex in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is equivalent to its interior being a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^2\,$, so the latter edit did not change the essence of the question.

Comment: I am not talking about edit !  I myself thought,  by saying the closeness of $f(x,y) = C$ means that it is a (topological)closed subset of $R^2$. Same in convexity, I thought the curve is a closed subset of $R^2$. These are what confused me.  I dont get what  you mean by this Then, a closed curve being convex in $R^2$ is equivalent to its interior being a closed set in $R^2$. dont get what